# Exponential Map, Cross Product

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G=\mathbb{R}^3$, $0\neq x\in G$, and $X$ be the linear transformation of $p\mapsto (x\times p)$ of $G$ (cross product). Choose a right-handed orthogonal basis $(e_{1},e_{2},e_{3})$ for G, with $e_{3}$ a unit vector parallel to $x$. I want to show that 
$$exp(X)e_{1}=cos||x||e_{1}+sin||x||e_{2},$$
$$exp(X)e_{2}=-sin||x||e_{1}+cos||x||e_{2},$$
and
$$exp(X)e_{3}=e_{3}.$$
I really don't know what to do with this one. I have read the theory about the exponential map and Lie groups/algebras, but I really struggle finding it. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The case $x=0$ is easy. Suppose $x\ne0$. If $x=\|x\|e_3$, then
\begin{cases}
Xe_1=x\times e_1=\|x\|(e_3\times e_1)=\|x\|e_2,\\
Xe_2=x\times e_2=\|x\|(e_3\times e_2)=-\|x\|e_1,\\
Xe_3=x\times e_3=0.
\end{cases}
Now you may use the Taylor series for the exponential, since and cosine functions to finish the proof.